# Android Studio wireless ADB error (10061) (TV)

Tags: android, adb, android-tv

I see lots of posts everywhere showing how to connect to Android device using `adb connect <ip>` but in my case it's not working...

`unable to connect to <ip addr>:5555: cannot connect to <ip addr>:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)`

- Developer mode is OK;
- USB debugging is OK;
- Both computer and device are connected to same network;
- There is no USB port to plug (Android TV)

Before I was using another brand and it worked fine, I could connect it over wifi no problem, but after I switched to this brand called MXQ I can't manage to work it anymore. 
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long try I could finally find the solution. If anyone needs it, here is what I did.
On this brand (MXQ) there is two ways to access settings. The traditional Android way and:

1. Open Apps on the device and locate the App called `settings`
2. Enable USB debugging
3. After that you will be able to connect via USB (type A) available on the device
4. Connect to Android Studio just like usual.

*You will need a USB type A to A to do that..
** Make sure your USB cable has data wires ([check usb](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140225/how-can-i-tell-charge-only-usb-cables-from-usb-data-cables))

Comment: I tested with the A-A cable, it just does not show! Mine is MXQ-4K. Can you please tell in more details?

Comment: @JasonStack when you turn box on, and it finishes loading everything. You need to find settings on Apps, not the Android settings. On my box, on main screen (just loaded) there is a icon called `apps`, click it and look for the app called `settings`, try to open, it will look different from the Android settings panel. There you will find the developer session and then you can activate usb debbuging... Its crazy, but it's the only way i found it.

Comment: Wow that's odd. I'll try it as soon as I get back to the office.

Comment: I have enabled USB debugging. And I went through something similar to what you said. But, still I do not see the device.

Comment: @JasonStack I took some photos of the screens, please take a look at [images](https://imgur.com/a/uy7nU) As soon as I change USB settings to Connected to computer, Android studio logcat recognize it.

Comment: Thanks for the images. What type of USB cable are you using?

Comment: Here i'm using Type A to A. This is another important thing to check. Most of A to A cables are used to power laptop tables's fan and it has only the power wires, you need to make sure to have the data wires.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But, how should I know if it has data channels?

Comment: You have two options. One with multimeter as shown [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140225/how-can-i-tell-charge-only-usb-cables-from-usb-data-cables ) or trying another cable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do following steps (In most cases this happen in Huawei devices)

- Revoke USB debugging authorizations Allow ADB debugging in charge
- only mode (I think this fixed the issue) Turn off Always prompt when
  connecting to USB

Main steps:

open Cmd,

1. adb kill-server
2. Connect your phone with usb cable and enable debugging and select file transfer (MTP)
3. adb tcpip 5555     (Port Number)
4. Disconnect device unplug usb cable
5. adb connect YourDeviceIpAddress:5555

Comment: Even though is very simple, It worked for me.